# Trigger.AvailableNow for Delta source streaming queries in PySpark (Databricks)

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

All the examples in the Databricks [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/10.1.html#triggeravailablenow-for-delta-source-streaming-queries) are in Scala. Can't find how to use this trigger type from PySpark. Is there an equivalent API or workaround ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python implementation missed the Spark 3.2 release, so it will be included into Spark 3.3 only (for OSS version). On Databricks it was released as part of DBR 10.3 (or 10.2?), and could be used as following:

```
.trigger(availableNow=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.ss/api/pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.trigger.html):

```py
DataStreamWriter.trigger(*, processingTime: Optional[str] = None, 
                            once: Optional[bool] = None, 
                            continuous: Optional[str] = None, 
                            availableNow: Optional[bool] = None) -> pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter
```

> **availableNow**: bool, optional
>
> if set to True, set a trigger that processes all available data in multiple >batches then terminates the query. Only one trigger can be set.

```py
# trigger the query for reading all available data with multiple batches
writer = sdf.writeStream.trigger(availableNow=True)
```